# How to bind object list in a form submission to a spring @RequestBody with Thymeleaf

Tags: json, spring-mvc, data-binding, thymeleaf, forms, http-post

I am trying to bind a list of object in Spring controller that is annotated with `@RequestBody`. I am using Thymeleaf for template engine. I am using `Kotlin` programming language.

Here is the HTML code

```
<form class="attendanceBook" id="form_submit" role="form" method="post" action="/attendances">
                <table class="table table-striped">
                    <th>Role Number</th>
                    <th style="width: 30%">Student Name</th>
                    <th>Present</th>
                    <div th:each="std, stat : ${studentList}" class="separator">
                        <tr>
                            <td th:text="${std.roleNumber}"></td>
                            <td th:text="${std.studentName}"></td>
                            <td><input type="checkbox" th:name="|i[__${stat.index}__]|" id="i" /></td>
                            <td><input type="text" th:name="|t[__${stat.index}__]|" th:value="*{studentList[__${stat.index}__].studentId}"/> </td>
                        </tr>
                    </div>
                </table>
                <input type="submit" id="submit_btn" value="Click"/>
            </form>
```

When I submit the form that converted to the Json format with jQuery. Here is only that JavaScript part which convert form data to  Json.

```
var genFormSubmitParams = function (context) {
    var _this = $(context),
        data = {};
    _this.find('[name]').each(function (index, value) {
        var _this = $(this),
            name = _this.attr('name'),
            value = _this.val();
        data[name] = value;
    });
    var params = {};
    params["data"] = JSON.stringify(data);
    console.log(params["data"]);
    return params;
};
```

Here is the Controller.

```
@PostMapping
fun patchAttendance(@RequestBody attendanceJson: AttendanceJsonWrapper): ResponseEntity<*> {
{
    logger.info("attendanceJson list size {}", attendanceJson.attendanceJsons?.size)
    logger.info("attendanceJson {}", attendanceJson)

    return responseOK(attendanceJson)
}
```

This is the data class in which I need to bind one single row.

```
data class AttendanceJson (
    var i: String = "",
    var t: String = ""
)
```

And here is the wrapper class for the actual data class for list of object. I have written this in Java.

```
public class AttendanceJsonWrapper {
List<AttendanceJson> attendanceJsons;

public AttendanceJsonWrapper() {
}

public AttendanceJsonWrapper(List<AttendanceJson> attendanceJsons) {
    this.attendanceJsons = attendanceJsons;
}

public List<AttendanceJson> getAttendanceJsons() {
    return attendanceJsons;
}

public void setAttendanceJsons(List<AttendanceJson> attendanceJsons) {
    this.attendanceJsons = attendanceJsons;
}
}
```

When I am posting the JavaScript console show this in log

```
{"i[0]":"on","t[0]":"90","i[1]":"on","t[1]":"106"}
```

But it is not binding in the data class `AttendanceJson` as object. The `attendanceJsons` list remain null but the ajax call has success.

How can I bind this object list to back end ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

try `.serializeArray()` from jquery

`$( "form" ).submit(function( event ) {
  console.log( $( this ).serializeArray() );
  event.preventDefault();
});`

`https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/`